# Removing CSS whitespace

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on putting together a webpage for my wife and I've run into a CSS issue that I can't figure out. I have an image slider (RoyalSlider) that I want to have no whitespace around, but various nested divs before the slider div add padding, margins, and borders. The classes and the formatting within the classes are used in multiple places on the page, so I can't simply change the each element without breaking other elements of the page, and I would *prefer* to do this without messing with the PHP.

Here are the divs that are causing the formatting, tabbed in to represent how they are nested, below each div is the CSS formatting of the div.

```
<div class="container">
    #section-content .container {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    #section-content .container {
        border-left: 10px solid white;
        border-right: 10px solid white;
    }

        <div class="eleven columns content sixteen no-thumbnail">
            .content {
                padding: 10px 0 0;
            }

            .column, .columns {
                float: left;
                display: inline;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }

                <div class="the_content post type-post hentry excerpt clearfix">
                    .content .hentry {
                        padding-bottom: 15px;
                    }

                    <div class="royalSlider">
                        <div class="rsOverflow">
                            <div class="rsContainer">
```

I thought that I could do something with a bunch of > (or something... my CSS skills are rudimentary) to specify that when the royalSlider div was present that it would override all the other rules, but I can't figure out how to do it.

The URL of the page is here:

http://rachelhappen.com/high-res-royal-test-post/

Here is a picture showing how it is now, how I'd like it to be, and color coded graphic of the way the CSS formats it.

[image: image of the webpage]
<sub>(source: [rachelhappen.com](http://rachelhappen.com/wp-content/uploads/borders.jpg))</sub>

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the royalslider in a div with an ID, then target the classes within the ID only so that your padding, margin, border changes won't affect other elements?

Comment: What's the syntax for this? I tried something like it before, but it just didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the classes hierarchy. I'm assuming that `royalSlider` is definately going to be there, then you can try to use its hierarchy to specify rules intended for it.

[Example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/uxqrqccr)

You can try

```
.container .royalSlider{
/* rules here */
}
```

Hope it helps.

[**Edit**] : So your problem is the padding lies in the parent and hence the issue.

[Problem](http://cssdeck.com/labs/eobgg0uf)

[Work around](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xn69tmxb) ==> try the same background color on the container - to hide the white space. Not a perfect solution - Just a Work around.Not suitable if you want the image to be centered

Comment: Thanks, I still can't seem to get it to remove whitespace though. 

I've looked at your example and I've modified it to be closer to what it is I'm trying to do...

[Modified Example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xvymdz5y)

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Vivek, what a great, sneaky solution! I think this is probably what I'll go with as I have discovered that what I'm trying to do isn't currently possible with CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

give the image an ID and set its padding to 0, 0, 0, 0, and if there is still some white space under the image, put the display attribute to block;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It's actually already in an ID #new-royalslider-5, so I tried adding this:

#new-royalslider-5 {
padding: 0;
display: block;
}

Doesn't appear to change anything.

Comment: why do you have so many divs in the first place? anyway, I use Opera and there is a feature - Opera Dragonfly, you activate it and click any element and it shows you the source code and exactly where it is... 
When I click the image, I see that the margin top has -10px 
Now, the image itself adds white space, and 3 other divs besides it also have some 10-20 px each adding the white space
if you use Dragonfly, you can detect all these divs and change their background color to that bluish one you want...

Comment: Oh, also, you are giving each element multiple classes, that is what may be messing up the code - multiple classes mean one property with more different values

Comment: I know where the white space is coming from. I just don't know how to review the whitespace without changing everything else. I think what I'm trying to do is a "parent selector" which apparently is only in CSS4. :P Thanks...